# Windows 10: Output sound to 3 or more monitors simultaneously

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, display, multiple-monitors

I know that there is a built-in method in Windows 10 in where you can output sound to 2 devices (monitors) simultaneously. But for my case I have in total 3 monitors in which I would like to know if there is a software in which allows you to output sound to 3 or even more devices (monitors) simultaneously?

I have the following

1. One AOC monitor connected to a Dell docking station with HDMI-cable
2. One ASUS monitor connected directly to my laptop also with HDMI-cable

The docking station is connected to my Dell Laptop through 2 USB-C connectors.

Let me know if you need additional details

Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: You can split a 3.5mm aux audio jack 3 ways, but are you talking about a different connection?

Comment: I didnt have any specific method in mind.

Comment: Just want a way in where I can output sound from my 3 devices, my laptop and the 2 other monitors.
One of the monitors are connected directly to the HDMI port of the laptop whereas the second monitor is connected to a dockingstation which in turn is connected to the laptop.

Comment: Please update your question to detail what connection types the monitors are & how they are connected. You mentioned HDMI, but what are the other two? Knowing the model of the following is likely to help us: sound card, laptop, graphics, monitor, etc.